# How much object initialization should I do in unit tests?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit

Let say I am unit testing a method that returns the count of cars in my garage so I have a method like this:

```
public class Garage {
    public long numberOfCarsInGarage() {
        return cars.size();
    }
}
```

From the test class:

```
@Test
public void numberOfCarsInGarage_returnsCount_whenCarsHaveBeenAddedToTheGarage() {
    Garage garage = new Garage();

    Car firstCar = new Car();
    Car secondCar = new Car();
    Car thirdCar = new Car();

    garage.addCars(firstCar, secondCar, thirdCar);

    assertEquals(3, garage.numberOfCarsInGarage());
}
```

Each car object has many properties to set, but I don't need to set them in order for the test to pass. Am I right that I should do the least possible code in the test to make it pass/fail? I am not doing anything wrong here by not setting dummy data on the car objects in the test?

Comment: You don't need to set fields which don't cause the test to fail. I would do the minimum which passes the test. Ideally you would do the minimum which fails first and then add code to make it pass.

Comment: What are the known side-effects of calling `garage.addCars(...);`. That's what your test should be covering.

Comment: I agree with the two above comments. My advice: Write the javadoc of the method under test, and verify that the contract stated in this javadoc is fulfilled. If the contract is "returns the total number of cars in the garage", then it should test that. If the contract is "returns the number of red cars in the garage", then it should add some red cars and some non-red cars, and test that. Writing the javadoc is helpful not only because it documents the method, but also because it makes you think about what you need to test, the edge cases, etc.

Comment: Your test is perfectly fine.

Comment: @JBNizet So you write JavaDoc for the tests too?

Comment: @LuckyLuke: no, usually not. My advice is to write the javadoc for the method being tested, not for the test method.

Answer (score 0):

For your use case as described, it seems fine not to set dummy data.  It really depends on the project.  I'm working on testing a complex distributed system involving 5 servers and multiple processes on each server.  Some of my tests handle small parts of that, but some are end to end tests for the entire system.  In my case, most of my test framework is setting up the environment.  The general rule though is that you should set up enough so that your test is likely to capture failures.  Whenever you find things that your test cases doesn't capture because it didn't set up enough, considering setting up more so that the test case will  capture that in the future.  Note that you're trying to balance test cases covering likely problems against making them simple enough to write that you can efficiently write them.

Answer (score 0):

If you're unit testing `numberOfCarsInGarage()` it means you want your test to fail only when something in that method goes wrong, then you should try to isolate its invocation from the rest of the stuff in the class.

I suggest avoid invoking `addCars()`, instead I would create a list of mock cars and I'd [set it in the SUT using reflection](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.5.6/api/org/springframework/test/util/ReflectionTestUtils.html).